# formatting web page check boxes into straight line

Tags: html, css

okay so my question is simple is there a way to center a list of check boxes but keep the check boxes in one line instead of a wave pattern? here is what I have as of right now.

```
     html>
     <Head>
     <center>
     <div style="background-color:grey;color:black;border:5px solid black;width:600px;height:500px;font-size:18px;">
     <H1>Select a program you want to run.</H1>
     <A href="file://C:\Windows/notepad.exe">Notepad</a>
     <div>
     <a href="file://D:\My Documents">Documents</a>
     <div>
     <a href="file://D:\Desktop\Student Applications">programs</a>
     <div>
     <a href="http://pilot.wright.edu">Pilot</a>
     <div>
     <form>
     <input type="checkbox" oncheck="file://D:\My Documents\1 CCE">CCE</input>
     <div>
     <input type="checkbox">A3</input>
     <div>
     <input type="checkbox">CR</input>
     <div>
     <input type="checkbox">CPR</input>
     <div>
     <input type="checkbox">MM</input>
     <div>
     <input type="checkbox">IR</input>
     <div>
     <button type="submit" id="34">SUBMIT</button>
     </form>
     </center>
     </head>
     </html>
```

once you open this as an HTML you should be able to see what I am talking about. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put this in a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) for us.  Your HTML is a bit messy, `center` is deprecated, etc.

Comment: For starters, you can't put the HTML in the HEAD.

Comment: Not going to help, but you need end tags for all of your <div>s (which aren't themselves even necessary). Inputs are also going to get parsed as "<input type="checkbox" />A3". You'll want value attributes on those checkboxes.

Comment: THank you to every one who answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS_STEM: First thing I'd do is make sure you close all your html elements.

If you want these as a list in a straight line then make it a list rather than a bunch of divs, like so:

```
<div class="checkbox-list">
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" oncheck="file://D:\My Documents\1 CCE">CCE</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">A3</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">CR</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">CPR</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">MM</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">IR</input></li>
</ul>
<button type="submit" id="34">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

It will look cleaner and other programmers will quickly see what you meant :)

Also, maybe it should be put in the body.  They whole thing should look a bit more like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-color:grey;color:black;border:5px solid black;width:600px;height:500px;font-size:18px;">
<H1>Select a program you want to run.</H1>
<a href="file://C:\Windows/notepad.exe">Notepad</a>
<a href="file://D:\My Documents">Documents</a>
<a href="file://D:\Desktop\Student Applications">programs</a>
<a href="http://pilot.wright.edu">Pilot</a>
<div class="checkbox-list">
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" oncheck="file://D:\My Documents\1 CCE">CCE</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">A3</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">CR</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">CPR</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">MM</input></li>
<li><input type="checkbox">IR</input></li>
</ul>
<button type="submit" id="34">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I never thought to use a list but it certainly worked.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have each checkbox within a `div`, which has the property `display:block`, thus they appear on new lines. Either change the markup, and remove each `div` wrapped around the checkboxes.. or set `display:inline-block` or `float:left` on the `div` elements containing the checkboxes.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dZsTS/1/) - Easiest option - remove the `divs` around each checkbox.

If I misunderstood, and you wanted them lined vertically [**see this jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dZsTS/2/).

---

Aside from that there are some serious syntax errors that need to be fixed.

- `<center>` is soon to be depreciated, if not already is..
- You cannot put the `html` in the `head` tag.
- You didn't close most of the tags..

Comment: Some good recommendations, but I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Seth And what is he looking for?

Answer (score 1):

1. you are using centering `<center>`... remove the beginning/end CENTER tag first.
2. end all starting DIVs with an ending DIV.
3. In each DIV, add a style `style="text-align:left;"`

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code, you need to place your code in a <body> tag inside <html> tag.
Every <div> tag you open needs to be closed with a </div> tag or replace them with <br/> tags.

I think you can center your checkboxes by listing them and then aligning the list items to the left:

```
 <ul style='width:100px; list-style:none; border:1px solid black; text-align:left;'>
 <li><input type="checkbox" oncheck="file://D:\My Documents\1 CCE">CCE</input></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox">A3</input></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox">CR</input></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox">CPR</input></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox">MM</input></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox">IR</input></li>
 </ul>
```

Width = 100px makes the whole list alignable to center, text-align affects the items so they are left-aligned. I've added a border so you can see whats going on.

It would be good if you remove the <CENTER> tag and apply some CSS to center the whole list.

You can give this a try in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdZ6x/

Answer (score 1):

There are literally hundreds of ways for you to achieve what you ask.
Given your level of learning and given your approach, I would recommend this :

```
<html>
     <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #checkboxOptions {
                width: 100px;
                margin: 0 0 0 50px;
                border:5px solid red;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
     </head>
     <center>
         <div style="background-color:grey;color:black;border:5px solid black;width:600px;height:500px;font-size:18px;">
             <h1>Select a program you want to run.</h1>
             <a href="file://C:\Windows/notepad.exe">Notepad</a>
             <br />
             <a href="file://D:\My Documents">Documents</a>
             <br />
             <a href="file://D:\Desktop\Student Applications">programs</a>
             <br />
             <a href="http://pilot.wright.edu">Pilot</a>
             <br />
             <form>
                 <div id='checkboxOptions'>
                     <input type="checkbox" oncheck="file://D:\My Documents\1 CCE">CCE</input>
                     <br />
                     <input type="checkbox">A3</input>
                     <br />
                     <input type="checkbox">CR</input>
                     <br />
                     <input type="checkbox">CPR</input>
                     <br />
                     <input type="checkbox">MM</input>
                     <br />
                     <input type="checkbox">IR</input>
                 </div>
                 <button type="submit" id="34">SUBMIT</button>
             </form>
         </div>
     </center>
</html>
```

I have corrected the syntax errors I could find and have put the relevant styling into the head section of the document.
I have also added a rather obvious border around the div in question so you can see what it is doing.
Play around with the width attribute and the margin property to arrange it how you like.